# Styling Android Menu (Android Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

How I can style my android menu like given image. When I click on the second tab I need to highlight the icon with Blue color, Something similar to first one with orange color.

So my doubt regarding designing the menu are:

- What control I need to use for implementing the feature
- If it is possible How I can customize the control to display like this.

I am a windows phone developer, Don't have that much expertise in android UI controls. Recently only I started developing an Android using Xamarin.

So anyone please help me to learn the control. I don't need a ready made answer. Please guide me to implement the same, by sharing some code snippets or web links

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are ActionBar Tabs, I'd recommend using [this](https://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) tool. You can configure the colors you'd like, then add the generated files to your project as a custom Style.

I have used this exact site with my Xamarin Android projects, and can verify it works as intended.

Comment: Using that how i can set image as background. I didn't see any option in that site. More over they are written like ActionBar is deprecated.. Any Idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a tab view with [this](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) Developer-Android example. There is an also color customization example [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html). And any configuration for customizing tabs can be made inside the class.